# How to fit an appropriate smooth curve over bar plot/histogram?

Tags: r

My imported data set consists of predetermined ranges and their probability density values. I have plotted this in a bar chart in R. So my plot shows a histogram, but to R its just a bar plot. However, I now need to put a curve on this bar chart for visualization purposes, using same data in bar chart.

The code I have used so far is creating a funny looking curve that doesn't fit appropriately to the bar chart...Any help would be hugely appreciated please!

Code used so far:

```
barplot(Data10$pdf, names = Data10$ï..Weight.Range, xlab = "Weight", ylab = "Probability Density", ylim = c(0.00,0.05), main = "Histogram")

fit1<-smooth.spline(Data10$ï..Weight.Range, Data10$pdf, df=12, spar = 0.2)
lines(fit1,col="blue", lwd=3)
```

Link to output of this code:

[image: output]

Data:

```
Data10 <- structure(list(
ï..Weight.Range = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 
3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 
11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 
17.5, 18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 
24, 24.5, 25, 25.5, 26, 26.5, 27, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5, 30, 
30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, 32.5, 33, 33.5, 34, 34.5, 35, 35.5, 36, 36.5, 
37, 37.5, 38, 38.5, 39, 39.5, 40, 40.5, 41, 41.5, 42, 42.5, 43, 
43.5, 44, 44.5, 45, 45.5, 46, 46.5, 47, 47.5, 48), pdf = c(0.012697609, 
0.015237131, 0.017776653, 0.019046414, 0.020694512, 0.022575831, 
0.024457151, 0.02633847, 0.028219789, 0.030101109, 0.031982428, 
0.033863747, 0.035745066, 0.037626386, 0.039507705, 0.041389024, 
0.043270343, 0.045151663, 0.042420729, 0.03688759, 0.033198831, 
0.029510072, 0.026374627, 0.023976934, 0.02264407, 0.021614794, 
0.020585518, 0.019556242, 0.018526967, 0.017497691, 0.016468415, 
0.015439139, 0.014409863, 0.013380587, 0.012351311, 0.011322035, 
0.009839476, 0.008433837, 0.007731017, 0.007028197, 0.005622558, 
0.004919738, 0.004568328, 0.004498046, 0.004427764, 0.004357482, 
0.0042872, 0.004216918, 0.004146636, 0.004076354, 0.004006072, 
0.00393579, 0.003865508, 0.003795226, 0.003724944, 0.003654663, 
0.003584381, 0.003514099, 0.003443817, 0.003373535, 0.003303253, 
0.003232971, 0.003162689, 0.003092407, 0.003022125, 0.002951843, 
0.002881561, 0.002811279, 0.002740997, 0.002670715, 0.002600433, 
0.002530151, 0.002459869, 0.002389587, 0.002319305, 0.002249023, 
0.002178741, 0.002108459, 0.002038177, 0.001967895, 0.001897613, 
0.001827331, 0.001757049, 0.001686767, 0.001616485, 0.001546203, 
0.001475921, 0.001405639, 0.001335357, 0.001265075, 0.001194794, 
0.001124512, 0.00105423, 0.000983948, 0.000913666, 0.000843384, 
0.000773102)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -97L))
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. If you're trying to treat this as a histogram, why not use `hist`?

Comment: Hi there, I haven't been able to use the hist since my data is already in weight ranges  with their probability density values. I don't have access to the raw data. I assumed it would be wrong to use hist on data that has predetermined ranges and probability density values... I am very new to R.. so maybe I was wrong to assume this? Ideally I need to curve to fit across the bar plot, and not sitting far to the left of it...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Without having your data that wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed in the initial barplot when drawing the new lines.

```
my_bar <- barplot(Data10$pdf, names = Data10$ï..Weight.Range, xlab = "Weight", ylab = "Probability Density", ylim = c(0.00,0.05), main = "Histogram")

fit1<-smooth.spline(Data10$ï..Weight.Range, Data10$pdf, df=12, spar = .2)

lines(my_bar, fit1$y,col="blue",type="l",lwd=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `barplot` function is meant to be used with a categorical variable. It is treating your x values as categories rather than a continuous number. When `barplot` runs, it calculates an value for each category which it silently returns. You can use those returned values with the result from your smooth spline to draw the line. For example

```
xx <- barplot(Data10$pdf, names = Data10$ï..Weight.Range, xlab = "Weight", ylab = "Probability Density", ylim = c(0.00,0.05), main = "Histogram")

fit1<-smooth.spline(Data10$ï..Weight.Range, Data10$pdf, df=12, spar = 0.2)
lines(xx[,1], fit1$y,col="blue", lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much!! Just one quick question - what is 'xx[,1]' doing in the lines command? Just so that I fully understand what you have done! Thanks, very much

Comment: `barplot` returns a matrix, i was just grabbing the first column of that matrix. If you pass in a simple vector of values to `barplot`, it doesn't really make much of a difference; i just wanted to be explicit.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the parameters from this curve?

Comment: There is no closed form for a smooth.spline. It’s a function of the observed data. If you want some sort of parameterized line, would would need to do some type of model fitting.